# Get html third child element id on click at the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a generate that code using Html:

```
<td align="center">
  <div class="popup" onclick="ChooseImageToolTip(this)">
      <a class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture">
           <span class="popuptext" id=@TableRowId>A Simple Popup!</span>
        </span>
     </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

and i need to get the id of the class="popuptext" span element, and proccess it in the ChooseImageToolTip() javascript function.
I pass the div element to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a reference to the `div` containing the element. So in your function, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to find the `.popuptext` element, and read its `id` property:

```
function ChooseImageToolTip(element) {
    alert("ID: " + element.querySelector(".popuptext").id);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function ChooseImageToolTip(element) {
  alert("ID: " + element.querySelector(".popuptext").id);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="popup" onclick="ChooseImageToolTip(this)">
          <a class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture">
           <span class="popuptext" id="row1">A Simple Popup!</span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="popup" onclick="ChooseImageToolTip(this)">
          <a class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture">
           <span class="popuptext" id="row2">A Simple Popup!</span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="popup" onclick="ChooseImageToolTip(this)">
          <a class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture">
           <span class="popuptext" id="row3">A Simple Popup!</span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div class="popup" onclick="ChooseImageToolTip(this)">
          <a class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture">
           <span class="popuptext" id="row4">A Simple Popup!</span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an elements id from its class like so.

```
 <span class="popuptext" id="abc">A Simple Popup!</span>    
 <script>
 var x = document.querySelector('.popuptext').id;
 console.log(x); //Would print abc
 </script>
```